# Here's what I have in my style sheet li {display:inline; } li.vert (color:red;} How do I get li.vert to display vertically

Tags: css, list, inline

My question is about having a vertical list after an inline list

```
li {display:inline;}   
li.vert (color:red;}
```

How do I get li.vert to display vertically   it displays red OK but inline

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to ignore `li` items with the class `.vert` or reset the display property for `.vert`

Using `:not()` applies the styles to all `li` but not `li` with the class `.vert`

```css
li.vert {
  color: red
}

li:not(.vert) {
  display: inline;
}

ul.vert>li {
  display: list-item
}
```

```html
<h3>mixed list</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>


<h3>inline list</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
</ul>


<h3>vertical list</h3>
<ul>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
  <li class="vert">list item </li>
</ul>

<h3>simplified vertical list</h3>
<ul class="vert">
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
</ul>
```

but really, you should be giving the list you want to modify a class instead of applying a property to all `li` elements.

Like so

```css
ul.foo>li {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Default List</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>


<h3>modified List</h3>
<ul class="foo">
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to use the ul rather than li.

```css
.list li{
  display:inline;
  }
  
.vert {
  color:red;
  display:auto !important;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Other Stuff</li>
  <li>More other stuff</li>
</ul>

<ul class="vert">
  <li>Junk</li>
  <li>Other Junk</li>
  <li>More other junk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris Do I have to set vert as a class for li?

Comment: No, you can just add it to the ul. There are a few different ways to do what you're asking. This is just the way I would. You can do it using an id instead of a class also.

Comment: Hi Chris  I appreciate your help but I am still having a problem using ul. Here is my complete file. The problem item is ul class vertical right at the end of the file.

Comment: Chris this is a snippet - I hope you can see what I am trying to do
#Links {border-width: 3px; }
}
.navlinks  {position: absolute; top: 9px; left: 5px; }
 .li {margin: ;display: inline;}


#Lateral{
 border-width: 3px; }
.li {display:inline; padding: }

ul.vertical {
 color:red;
  display:auto}



<DIV id="lateral" >
 <UL class="lat">
  <li><img src="</li>
 </UL>
</DIV>

<DIV id="container">
<DIV id="pix">
 <img src=>
 
    </DIV>
<DIV id="content">
  <P> </p>
 
 <ul class="vertical"> 
  <li >walk1</li>
  <li >walk2</li>
 </ul>
 
 </DIV>

Comment: There are several problems. Can you post what you have in a jsfiddle and link it here please? jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi Chris sorry for delay- I have been on other things. I put myHTML and CSS into  jsfiddle but it showed no errors but I was still unable to get verticallisting. How do I link it to here?